# local variable T conflicts with a static parameter warining

Tags: class, object, types, static, julia

I'm getting warning that I don't understand.

I first run the following code:

```
type PDF{T <: Real}
    ::Vector{Float64} # K
    μs::Matrix{T} # D x K
    Σs::Vector{Matrix{T}} # K{D x D}
end


type Q{T <: Real}
    w::Union{Float64, Vector{Float64}}
    μpair::Union{Vector{T}, Matrix{T}}
    Σpair::Union{Matrix{T}, Tuple{Matrix{T}, Matrix{T}} } # K{D x D}
end

type Smod{T <: Real}
    H::Matrix{T} # D x D
    Σs::Vector{Matrix{T}} # K{D x D}
    qs::Vector{Q{T}}
end


type Scale{T <: Real}
    μ::Vector{T} # D
    Σ::Matrix{T} # D x D
end

type Parameters{T <: Real}
    scale::Scale{T}
    w::Vector{Float64}
    maxNumCompsBeforeCompression::Integer
    numComponentsAbsorbed::Integer
end

type KDE{T}
    pdf::PDF{T}
    smod::Smod{T}
    params::Parameters{T}
end
```

And when after this I run the following snippet in IJulia

```
function initializeKDE{T <: Real}(x::Vector{T})

    d = size(x,1)
    T = typeof(x)

     = ones(Float64, 1)
    μs = Array(T, d,1)
    μs[:,1] = x
    Σs = Array(Matrix{T}, 0)
    pdf = PDF(, μs, Σs)

    H = zeros(T, d,d)
    qs = Array(Q{T}, 0)
    smod = Smod(H, Σs, qs)

    scale = Scale(x, H)

    w = [0.0, 1.0]

    maxNumCompsBeforeCompression = min(10, (0.5d^2 + d))
    numComponentsAbsorbed = 0
    params = Params(scale, w, maxNumCompsBeforeCompression, numComponentsAbsorbed)

    kde = KDE(pdf, smod, params)

    return kde::KDE
end
```

I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: local variable T conflicts with a static parameter in initializeKDE at In[4]:3.
```

where `In[4]:3` corresponds to the 3rd line of the 2nd snippet.

Can anyone explain in human english what this warning is saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is saying that you are trying to use `T` in two different ways: once as a "static parameter" and once as a local variable.

Firstly, you are using `T` as the parameter with which you are parametrising the function `initializeKDE`:

```
function initializeKDE{T <: Real}(x::Vector{T})
```

But then you are trying to redefine a new `T` in that third line:

```
    T = typeof(x)
```

What are you trying to do here? If you are trying to define `T` to be the type of the elements that the vector `x` contains, then you should just delete this line and everything should just work -- `T` will automatically take the element type (`eltype`) of the vector that you pass to the `initializeKDE` function.